# Trouble reaching a websocket server from some vps but not the others?

Tags: networking, websocket, vps, lan

So, I have several vps and public clouds server going on. On one of the server I want to setup a websocket server. Now, I can reach the websocket server via the public ip address and port 443 on most other vps. But I can't reach the websocket server public ip with servers I got from the same company.

I suspect it's due to the websocket being on the same lan? Is there such thing as not being able to reach a public ip if you're on the same lan.. And how do I fix this? Systems are run on linux.

I'm sure there is a simple fix.. such as connecting to a local ip somehow instead of the public one, but I just can't find it..

Server:

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');



const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 443 })



wss.on('connection', wss => {
    wss.send(`connected`);
});
```

Client:

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
let addr = `http://<mypublicip,omitted>:443/`;




console.log(`connecting to ${addr}`);
var ws = new WebSocket(addr);



ws.onmessage = m => {
    console.log(m.data);
}
```